# Plotting in a single plot in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

So, I am new in Python. I have 484 txt files of spacecraft data.The files are named WI_H0_MFI_1, WI_H0_MFI_2 ......WI_H0_MFI_484. I want to plot all of these 484 txt files in a single plot, but I am having no success. I used the following code but to no avail.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
filelist=[]
for i in range(1,485):
    filelist.append("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/WI_H0_MFI_%s.txt" %i)
for fname in filelist:
    data=np.loadtxt(fname)
    x=data[:,1]
    x_1= x - data[0,1]
    x_2= x_1 - 86400
    x_3 = x_2/3600
    Y=data[:,2]
    np.clip(Y,0,None)
    plt.plot(x_3, np.clip(Y,0,None))
plt.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome here on Stack Overflow! Can you describe what doesn't work? What do you see (or don't see) and how is that different from what you expected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I use data=np.loadtxt(fname) and print(fname),it prints out all the file names in the sequential order but I get only 1 plot of a txt file, where I expected to get 484 plots. Any advice on how to loop through all of them will be really helpful.

Comment: The command to tell the computer to show the plot is `plt.show`. At the moment, you put it outside of the loop, and that is why you only have one output plot (you only see the last made). Try putting the command inside the loop ;-) The problem you will then have is that it's boring to visualize 484 plots... Why not saving them?

Comment: In the question you say you want one single plot, but in the comment you say you want 484 plots. Can you please be more precise and edit your question accordingly?

Comment: I apologize@ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I think I messed up, basically, i want to plot all of my 484 text files in a single plot but individually.

Comment: Thanks a lot@albus_c. That simple trick worked wonders, I have seen a couple of my txt files have bad data points which are messing up my plots, so any advice how can I loop over them?For example, I just saw 1 and 37 no. txt files are bad, so I want to exclude them from the range.

Comment: `if i == 1 or if i == 37: break` will let you out of the first loop. In this way the files are excluded from `filelist` and you are home safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot@albus_c

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it super easy and merge the files using the terminal command `cat` first... see [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318777/combine-multiple-text-files-into-one-file). Then load the combined file and plot.

Syntax: `cat file1 newline file2 newline file3 > newfile`

Comment: This works if you want to plot all datasets as a single one. If you need to plot each dataset separately, then there is some extra work.

Comment: Thanks albus_c for your reply, I want to plot them individually but on a single plot. So looking for any loop options that will run through each of them and plot.